# Can the iPhone act as the NFC tag itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I try to adjust the transfer of data between 2 iPhones with the help of NFC tag (that one device acted as a scanner and the other played a tag). Didn't find anything on the internet. Write that the iPhone can only write data to the NFC tag. So the question is: Can the iPhone act as the NFC tag itself?